# Import multiple .csv files to mysql using bash

Tags: mysql, bash, mysqlimport

I would like to use a bash script to first copy files from a google drive to the local drive and rename (to remove the spaces and to add a prefix) and then import these .csv files into a mysql database. These .csv's have different columns so i need to get the column names from each .csv and create a table using these column names and then import the data.

I would appreciate any help.

I found some code here https://ericlondon.com/2011/04/10/a-bash-shell-script-to-import-a-large-number-of-csv-files-into-mysql.html which i have modified but i cant get it to work. I admit i dont understand what it all does.

This is what i currently have for my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# show commands being executed, per debug
set -x

# define database connectivity
_db="dbname"
_db_user="user"
_db_password="password"

# delete existing files
rm -rf /path/to/*.csv

# copy files to local disk
cp /old/path/to/*.csv /path/to/

# define directory containing CSV files
_csv_directory="/path/to"

# go into directory
cd $_csv_directory || exit

# edit file name
rename "s/ //g" *.csv
rename "s/^/tp/g" *.csv

# get a list of CSV files in directory
_csv_files=`ls -1 *.csv`

# loop through csv files
for _csv_file in ${_csv_files[@]}
do

  # remove file extension
  _csv_file_extensionless=`echo "$_csv_file" | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/'`

  # define table name
  _table_name="${_csv_file_extensionless}"

  # get header columns from CSV file
  _header_columns=`head -1 $_csv_directory/$_csv_file | tr ',' '\n' | sed 's/"//' | sed 's/ /_/g'`
  _header_columns_string=`head -1 $_csv_directory/$_csv_file | sed 's/ /_/g' | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/(//g' | sed 's/)//g'`

  # ensure table exists
  mysql -u $_db_user -p$_db_password $_db << eof
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \`$_table_name\` ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
eof

  # loop through header columns
  for _header in "${_header_columns[@]}"
  do

    # add column
    mysql -u $_db_user -p$_db_password $_db --execute="alter table \`$_table_name\` add column IF NOT EXISTS \`$_header\` text"

  done

  # import csv into mysql
  mysqlimport --fields-enclosed-by='"' --fields-terminated-by=',' --lines-terminated-by="\r\n" --columns=$_header_columns_string -u $_db_user -p$_db_password $_db $_csv_directory/$_csv_file

done
exit
```

This is the updated output i get for each .csv:

```
++ for _csv_file in ${_csv_files[@]}
+++ echo tpTriplexBC.csv
+++ sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/'
++ _csv_file_extensionless=tpTriplexBC
++ _table_name=tpTriplexBC
+++ head -1 /path/to/tpTriplexBC.csv
+++ tr , '\n'
+++ sed 's/^"//'
+++ sed 's/"$//'
+++ sed 's/ /_/g'
+++ sed 's/(//g'
+++ sed 's/)//g'
++ _header_columns='ProductName
ProductID
Quantity
Tax
Paper_Type
PriceExpress
Production_Days_Express
PriceStandard
Production_Days_Standard
PriceSaver
Production_Days_Saver
PriceSameday
Production_Days_Sameday
Price_Just_Print
Price_File_Check
Price_File_Check_with_Proofing
Price_File_Assist
Artwork_Tax
Size
Flat_Width_mm
Flat_Height_mm
Finished_Width_mm
Finished_Height_mm
productionDataJSON
'pdatedAt"
+++ head -1 /path/to/tpTriplexBC.csv
+++ sed 's/ /_/g'
+++ sed 's/"//g'
+++ sed 's/(//g'
+++ sed 's/)//g'
++ _header_columns_string=$'ProductName,ProductID,Quantity,Tax,Paper_Type,PriceExpress,Production_Days_Express,PriceStandard,Production_Days_Standard,PriceSaver,Production_Days_Saver,PriceSameday,Production_Days_Sameday,Price_Just_Print,Price_File_Check,Price_File_Check_with_Proofing,Price_File_Assist,Artwork_Tax,Size,Flat_Width_mm,Flat_Height_mm,Finished_Width_mm,Finished_Height_mm,productionDataJSON,updatedAt\r'
++ mysql -u user -ppassword dbname
++ for _header in ${_header_columns[@]}
++ mysql -u user -ppassword dbname '--execute=ALTER TABLE `tpTriplexBC` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `ProductName` text'
++ for _header in ${_header_columns[@]}
++ mysql -u user -ppassword dbname '--execute=ALTER TABLE `tpTriplexBC` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `ProductID` text'
++ for _header in ${_header_columns[@]}
++ mysql -u user -ppassword dbname '--execute=ALTER TABLE `tpTriplexBC` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `Quantity` text'
++ for _header in ${_header_columns[@]}
++ mysql -u user -ppassword dbname '--execute=ALTER TABLE `tpTriplexBC` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `Tax` text'
++ for _header in ${_header_columns[@]}
++ mysql -u user -ppassword dbname '--execute=ALTER TABLE `tpTriplexBC` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `Paper_Type` text'
++ for _header in ${_header_columns[@]}
++ mysql -u user -ppassword dbname '--execute=ALTER TABLE `tpTriplexBC` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `PriceExpress` text'
++ for _header in ${_header_columns[@]}
++ mysql -u user -ppassword dbname '--execute=ALTER TABLE `tpTriplexBC` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `Production_Days_Express` text'
++ for _header in ${_header_columns[@]}
++ mysql -u user -ppassword dbname '--execute=ALTER TABLE `tpTriplexBC` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `PriceStandard` text'
++ for _header in ${_header_columns[@]}
++ mysql -u user -ppassword dbname '--execute=ALTER TABLE `tpTriplexBC` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `Production_Days_Standard` text'
++ for _header in ${_header_columns[@]}
++ mysql -u user -ppassword dbname '--execute=ALTER TABLE `tpTriplexBC` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `PriceSaver` text'
++ for _header in ${_header_columns[@]}
++ mysql -u user -ppassword dbname '--execute=ALTER TABLE `tpTriplexBC` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `Production_Days_Saver` text'
++ for _header in ${_header_columns[@]}
++ mysql -u user -ppassword dbname '--execute=ALTER TABLE `tpTriplexBC` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `PriceSameday` text'
++ for _header in ${_header_columns[@]}
++ mysql -u user -ppassword dbname '--execute=ALTER TABLE `tpTriplexBC` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `Production_Days_Sameday` text'
++ for _header in ${_header_columns[@]}
++ mysql -u user -ppassword dbname '--execute=ALTER TABLE `tpTriplexBC` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `Price_Just_Print` text'
++ for _header in ${_header_columns[@]}
++ mysql -u user -ppassword dbname '--execute=ALTER TABLE `tpTriplexBC` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `Price_File_Check` text'
++ for _header in ${_header_columns[@]}
++ mysql -u user -ppassword dbname '--execute=ALTER TABLE `tpTriplexBC` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `Price_File_Check_with_Proofing` text'
++ for _header in ${_header_columns[@]}
++ mysql -u user -ppassword dbname '--execute=ALTER TABLE `tpTriplexBC` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `Price_File_Assist` text'
++ for _header in ${_header_columns[@]}
++ mysql -u user -ppassword dbname '--execute=ALTER TABLE `tpTriplexBC` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `Artwork_Tax` text'
++ for _header in ${_header_columns[@]}
++ mysql -u user -ppassword dbname '--execute=ALTER TABLE `tpTriplexBC` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `Size` text'
++ for _header in ${_header_columns[@]}
++ mysql -u user -ppassword dbname '--execute=ALTER TABLE `tpTriplexBC` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `Flat_Width_mm` text'
++ for _header in ${_header_columns[@]}
++ mysql -u user -ppassword dbname '--execute=ALTER TABLE `tpTriplexBC` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `Flat_Height_mm` text'
++ for _header in ${_header_columns[@]}
++ mysql -u user -ppassword dbname '--execute=ALTER TABLE `tpTriplexBC` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `Finished_Width_mm` text'
++ for _header in ${_header_columns[@]}
++ mysql -u user -ppassword dbname '--execute=ALTER TABLE `tpTriplexBC` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `Finished_Height_mm` text'
++ for _header in ${_header_columns[@]}
++ mysql -u user -ppassword dbname '--execute=ALTER TABLE `tpTriplexBC` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `productionDataJSON` text'
++ for _header in ${_header_columns[@]}
++ mysql -u user -ppassword dbname '--execute=ALTER TABLE `tpTriplexB` text'COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `updatedAt"
'RROR 1166 (42000) at line 1: Incorrect column name 'updatedAt"
++ mysqlimport '--fields-enclosed-by="' --fields-terminated-by=, '--lines-terminated-by=\n' $'--columns=ProductName,ProductID,Quantity,Tax,Paper_Type,PriceExpress,Production_Days_Express,PriceStandard,Production_Days_Standard,PriceSaver,Production_Days_Saver,PriceSameday,Production_Days_Sameday,Price_Just_Print,Price_File_Check,Price_File_Check_with_Proofing,Price_File_Assist,Artwork_Tax,Size,Flat_Width_mm,Flat_Height_mm,Finished_Width_mm,Finished_Height_mm,productionDataJSON,updatedAt\r' -u user -ppassword dbname /path/to/tpTriplexBC.csv
mysqlimport: Error: 1054, Unknown column 'updatedAt' in 'field list', when using table: tpTriplexBC
++ exit
```

The columns are inserted to each table but no data. Also tables called -1 and ls are created which i dont want.

The first line of the csv is:
`"ProductName","ProductID","Quantity","Tax","Special Finish","Laminate","Sides Printed","Material","PriceStandard","Production Days Standard","PriceSaver","Production Days Saver","PriceSameday","Production Days Sameday","Price Just Print","Price File Check","Price File Check with Proofing","Price File Assist","Artwork Tax","Size","Flat Width (mm)","Flat Height (mm)","Finished Width (mm)","Finished Height (mm)","productionDataJSON","updatedAt"`

Octal Dump output for the header:

```
0000000   "   P   r   o   d   u   c   t   N   a   m   e   "   ,   "   P
0000020   r   o   d   u   c   t   I   D   "   ,   "   Q   u   a   n   t
0000040   i   t   y   "   ,   "   T   a   x   "   ,   "   P   a   p   e
0000060   r       T   y   p   e   "   ,   "   P   r   i   c   e   E   x
0000100   p   r   e   s   s   "   ,   "   P   r   o   d   u   c   t   i
0000120   o   n       D   a   y   s       E   x   p   r   e   s   s   "
0000140   ,   "   P   r   i   c   e   S   t   a   n   d   a   r   d   "
0000160   ,   "   P   r   o   d   u   c   t   i   o   n       D   a   y
0000200   s       S   t   a   n   d   a   r   d   "   ,   "   P   r   i
0000220   c   e   S   a   v   e   r   "   ,   "   P   r   o   d   u   c
0000240   t   i   o   n       D   a   y   s       S   a   v   e   r   "
0000260   ,   "   P   r   i   c   e   S   a   m   e   d   a   y   "   ,
0000300   "   P   r   o   d   u   c   t   i   o   n       D   a   y   s
0000320       S   a   m   e   d   a   y   "   ,   "   P   r   i   c   e
0000340       J   u   s   t       P   r   i   n   t   "   ,   "   P   r
0000360   i   c   e       F   i   l   e       C   h   e   c   k   "   ,
0000400   "   P   r   i   c   e       F   i   l   e       C   h   e   c
0000420   k       w   i   t   h       P   r   o   o   f   i   n   g   "
0000440   ,   "   P   r   i   c   e       F   i   l   e       A   s   s
0000460   i   s   t   "   ,   "   A   r   t   w   o   r   k       T   a
0000500   x   "   ,   "   S   i   z   e   "   ,   "   F   l   a   t    
0000520   W   i   d   t   h       (   m   m   )   "   ,   "   F   l   a
0000540   t       H   e   i   g   h   t       (   m   m   )   "   ,   "
0000560   F   i   n   i   s   h   e   d       W   i   d   t   h       (
0000600   m   m   )   "   ,   "   F   i   n   i   s   h   e   d       H
0000620   e   i   g   h   t       (   m   m   )   "   ,   "   p   r   o
0000640   d   u   c   t   i   o   n   D   a   t   a   J   S   O   N   "
0000660   ,   "   u   p   d   a   t   e   d   A   t   "  \r  \n
```

Comment: It would be a good exercise for you to go through the script and try to understand what each step does and understand the options used in each command. You'll learn a lot and improve your skills in general.

Comment: In your trace output, did you study the error message? There's something that doesn't look right: `...NOT EXISTS \`updatedAt"` ends in a double quote not a single back-tick. And the next line shows `'RROR... Incorrect column name 'updatedAt"`. I suspect your `for _header in...` is picking up the last header name as `updatedAt"`. You can also see it in the list of headers shown in the trace. In bash, if you do `for "a b c" ...` you'll get `"a`, `b`, and `c"` as the loop variable.

Comment: I have managed to fix the error 1054 about the unknown column Flat_Width_mm but the 'updatedAt' error still exists and i cant see why it is reading the header as 'pdatedAt" instead of updatedAt. It is in the same format in the csv file. I assume it is related to this line (i have edited from above to fix the other error):
_header_columns=`head -1 "$_csv_directory/$_csv_file" | tr ',' '\n' | sed 's/^"//' | sed 's/"$//' | sed 's/ /_/g' | sed 's/(//g' | sed 's/)//g'`
but i cant see what is causing it

Comment: Could you please show the first line of your CSV file? It looks like none of your column names contain a space, so I'm not sure why you have `s/ /_/g` in your list of substitutions, unless you're generalizing. Dump out what `_header_columns` look like.

Comment: That prints 'pdatedAt" as the value for that column. I still dont know whats causing it. My guess is thats its got something to do with it being the end of the row but i dont know why its replacing the u with a '.
I think i understand what that line is doing. Its transforming , into \n, removing the " at the start and end of each field, replacing spaces with _ and removing the brackets.
The column names in the csv do contain spaces, i used that command to change them to underscores. I will add the first line of the csv to my original post

Comment: I see, sorry missed that you have some column names with spaces. I tried your text processing command line on what you show as the first line of the CSV and it seems to do what's expected. Can you update your trace to show what it looks like now that you have fixed your error?

Comment: I've updated the output in the original post

Comment: Something is odd that I didn't notice before. Why isn't the command for the `updatedAt` column the same as the others? Your last command is, `--execute=ALTER TABLE `tpTriplexB` text'COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `updatedAt"` Note the `text'` rather than `ADD`. The error looks similar to the last as well with the word `ERROR` being corrupted to `RROR`. That might be an indicator of a non-displayable control character in the csv heading somewhere. You could try passing the header through `od -c` to see if there's anything unusual.

Comment: added the od -c output and updated the code to my current version. I did notice this too but cant see where it is coming from.

Comment: I think it's the `\r` at the end. Linux uses `\n` as a line terminator. Windows uses `\r\n` generally. So I think it's seeing the header string as `"updatedAt"\r`. Try running `dos2unix` on your CSV file, which should also take care of it (backup your CSV file first since `dos2unix` modifies the file directly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the `od` output of your CSV header, appears that you have a carriage return and line feed at the end of your CSV lines (the `\r\n` sequence). Did the CSV come from processing under Windows? `\r\n` is a common text line termination under Windows, whereas Linux uses only `\n`. The `\r` gets included as part of the string and is not considered part of the line termination. It also can yield strange looking output since the `\r` by itself, when output, resets the cursor position to the first column and subsequent characters display over the top of whatever may have been displayed on that same line previously.

I recommend running `dos2unix` on your CSV file first, then do your processing. I think that will clear up the odd error and help the processing of the rest of the file work properly as well.